Need Assistance with `intelij-sdk` Folder for Building Android Studio from `studio-main` Branch
I'm currently working on building Android Studio from the studio-main branch, but I've hit a blocker. It seems that the build process requires the intelij-sdk folder under the prebuilts directory, which is closed-source.
I've searched through third-party repositories and other resources but haven't been able to find a way to obtain or bypass this directory. I’m considering falling back to the older studio-master-dev branch which doesn't require this Sdk folder for building android studio, but it’s quite outdated.
I’m reaching out to see if anyone in the community has encountered this issue before and might have a workaround or any insights on how to get the intelij-sdk directory (or an equivalent) for building AS from main branch.
Any guidance, references, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I've searched through third-party repositories and other resources but haven't been able to find a way to obtain or bypass this directory.
